# Find specific value in string python

Tags: python, string, numbers

How can I find all numbers different of zero in a such string.
for example:

'\\0\\0.412583\\0.4415169\\0.4140446\\0.3750735\\0\\0.4128125\\0\\0'

I tried to use regex but it does not work

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are those `'\\'` in the string? One single (quoted) backslash or 2 consecutive backslashes?

Comment: *it does not work...* is not a useful description of the problem. Show and explain the code for your attempt, show any errors or explain why the result is not what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're regex allergic, you can use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with a classical *listcomp*.

Assuming (`s`) is your string, try this :

```
listOfNumbers = [float(n) for n in s.split("\\") if n not in ["", "0"]]
```

Output :
​

```
print(listOfNumbers)
#[0.412583, 0.4415169, 0.4140446, 0.3750735, 0.4128125]
```

Comment: I think this solution is much more elegant than a regex version. I would personally replace the conditional with `if n not in ["", "0"]`, but other than that I like it.

Comment: Fair enough, I updated my answer accordingly. Thanks ;)

Comment: Also the question wasn't clear on whether '\\' is an escaped backslash or two backslashes, so the split method might require a raw literal to get `r"\\"`, but that's entirely up to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but you can give a chance to this snipped:

```
import re

string = '\\0\\0.412583\\0.4415169\\0.4140446\\0.3750735\\0\\0.4128125\\0\\0'
numbers = re.findall(r'(?<!0)[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?', string)
print(numbers)
```

Let me know!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks a lot Sergio, I do not know very well regex syntax, I tried to use re.search but it did not work, your solution is better !